# Unsupported Media Type while trying to post an Image in my Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, .net-5

I have a project in .NET 5 where i created an API controller.

The following API should accept a file via a POST request and store it,

the issue is that when i try to post a file via Postman i get the following response:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "00-a7f303198aea8e4c9d6611d5d618714f-f5bb7af9fcd7594a-00"
}
```

Here is how my Controller method looks like:

```
[HttpPost("images")]
public async Task<string> UploadImage([FromBody] IFormFile file)
{
    string path = Path.Combine(_host.ContentRootPath, "img/" + file.FileName);
    using var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);

    return "uploaded";
}
```

What is wrong here?